# Python: mapping colors across surface plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, surface

Is there a way to map the color-scheme from one surface plot onto another?

For example, let's say I have:

```
    surf_1 = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='summer')
```

and

```
    surf_2 = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z-Q, cmap='summer')
```

Is there a way to map the colorscheme for the surface defined by Z-Q onto the surface defined by Z? In other words, I want to visualize `surf_1`, but I want its surface to take on the colors defined by `surf_2`.

For context, I am trying to visualize the colors of the fluctuations of a parameter (Z) around a variable height (Q), where Q is not necessarily equal to 0.

EDIT: Is there a way I could extract the colors in `surf_2` as an array, and use those colors as input colors for `surf_1`? Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ScalarMappable()` function to create all colors to use as `facecolors` in the two surface plots. Here is the runnable code that demonstrates the steps to achieve what you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
fig.set_size_inches([10, 8])

# Make up data for 2 surfaces
X = np.logspace(0, np.log10(16), 50)
Y = np.linspace(3, 6, 50)
Z = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
# Convert to 2d arrays
Z = np.outer(Z.T, Z)        # 50x50
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)    # 50x50

# Make use of `ScalarMappable()` for custom color
# This use Z to get a colormap for plotting the surface
C = np.linspace(-1, 1, Z.size).reshape(Z.shape)
colormap = "summer"   # 'inferno' 'plasma' 'viridis'
scmap = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=colormap)

# for clarity, 2 surfaces are separated by some z shift
zshift = 80

# Upper-surface
# Note: ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z*X+zshift, cmap=colormap)
#  is almost equivalent with this
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z*X+zshift, facecolors=scmap.to_rgba(Z*X+zshift), shade=False)
# `shade=False` is used to suppress 3D shading

# Lower-surface
# Also use `facecolors=scmap.to_rgba(Z*X+zshift)`
# thus, equivalent with taking color from previous surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=scmap.to_rgba(Z*X+zshift), shade=False)

plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image: 2-surf]